# App installation failed: The application bundle does not contain an executable in Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, executable, swift4

I am getting this issue while installing application into my iphone 6s plus device.

[image]

This is whats happened.
Twitter kit was creating a problem. I deleted the POD folder and pod install and pod update TwitterKit. Everything sets up. added twitterkit framework in project. After clean build an build. Everything looks fine. Then i go to install app in device with the cable. I am getting this issue now.

Tried following ways

- Clean and Build again
- Deleted DerivedData path ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
- Deleted the "Executable file" entry from Info.plist and build again
- Quit Xcode and Reopened
- Restarted my MacBook also
- Deleted `~/.itmstransporter` in Bin folder
- In Build Setting 'Enable Bitcode' to No

None of the above solutions make it work. 
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks Ying and Sachin for your help and time. I appreciate that.
But I have figured out what went wrong.

The problem was with TwitterCore.framework in TwitterKit.

I looked into TwitterKit frameworks in Pods/TwitterKit/iOS/TwitterKit.framework/Info.plist, there was a key 'Executable file' with string value of 'TwitterKit' in it.

When i go in the same place in TwitterCore
Pods/TwitterKit/iOS/TwitterCore.framework/Info.plist, 'Executable file' key was missing. i added it with string 'TwitterCore'.

Problem solved. :)

Comment: Exactly the same issue here. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

Check your pinfo.list, if this setting is existing, if not add it:

```
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Yes it is already added in info.plist file.

Comment: You checked both info.lists? Project and testing?

Comment: Yes in all 3. Project, Test and UITest.

Comment: i am working in swift 4.
I have had like this with rounded bracket instead of { bracket.
 <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
Although i have checked with curly braces. No success

Comment: please check (in some other editor or Firefox, or online validator) if the pinfo.list files are valid xml files.

Comment: please try to make a hard-clean, too. (Shift-Alt-Cmd-K)

Answer (score 1):

- Remove all your extensions from **Build Phases > Target
  Dependencies** and **Build Phases > Embed App Extensions stages**.
- Run **Product > Clean**
- Try compiling
- Add your extensions one by one and do **Product > Clean + Product >
  Run** after adding each of them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i have no extension added in Build Phases > Target Dependencies.
Also didn't have this Embed App Extensions stages in Build Phases

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was caused by mis-setting of framework dependency.

#### Correct framework dpendency without error:

[image]

#### Problematic dependency giving `The application bundle does not contain an executable` error:

[image]

#### Conclusion:

make sure there are no duplicate framework dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same message and resolved this by changing the build system in the workspace settings.
In my case, the build system for "shared workspace settings" was on "new build system" and the build system fro "pre user workspace settings" was on legacy. Putting both on new build solved the problem.